# What did Slugworth offer the other children?

Tags: movie, roald-dahl, charlie-and-the-chocolate-factory, willy-wonka

In the film [*Willy Wonka and the Chocolate Factory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willy_Wonka_%26_the_Chocolate_Factory) (1971), we meet the character Slugworth who offers Charlie a bunch of money to get him an everlasting gobstopper. This made sense in context as a bribe for Charlie and his impoverished family. However, we also see that Slugworth approaches the other ticket winners, with the understanding that they too were being offered something in exchange for an everlasting gobstopper.

While it makes sense that Charlie was offered money, it really doesn't make so much sense that others, particularly Veruca Salt, were offered money. I always thought that it made more sense that the thing offered to each kid was tailored to their particular wants/needs. So what did Slugworth offer the other children?

Comment: Veruca may be rich, but her behaviour up until her downfall makes it pretty obvious she always wants much more the than what she's got.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Probably just money.**

Mike Teevee [asks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snB3vmY60Dk) whether his mother thinks that Slugworth would ***'pay extra'*** for additional secrets, implying that his bribe was financial. There's no obvious reason to assume that the other children wouldn't also want money.

> **WONKA:** *Oh, ginger ale, ginger pop, ginger beer, beer bubbles, bubble-ade, bubble cola, double cola, double bubble burp-a-cola, and all the crazy carbonated stuff that tickles your nose. Few people realize what tremendous power there is in one of those things.*
>
> **GRANDPA JOE:** *Sorry I asked.*
>
> **MIKE:** ***You think Slugworth would pay extra to know about this?***
>
> **MRS. TEEVEE:** *Just keep your eyes open and your mouth shut.*